# Java Divisional Error

Tags: java

Heres a snapshot my code:

```
int total = 2731;
String tmp = "I 1";
tmp = tmp.replaceAll("\\D", "");;
tmp = tmp.replaceAll("\\s+", "");;
int temp = Integer.parseInt(tmp);
double out = (double)temp / (double)total;
System.out.println(out);
```

This returns 3.661662394727206E-4 when by my calculations it should return

1.00/2731.00 = 0.00036616623

Can anybody tell me why this is the case?

Comment: @shekharsuman Actually, putting an answer down is better, as it is asked to avoid answering posts in a comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They're the same number:

```
0.0003 6616623
     3.661662394727206E-4
```

The `E-4` bit means `x 10-4` which means move the decimal point four places to the left.

If you were to output it instead with:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%.11f", out));
```

you would see that it's what you expected, albeit with proper rounding in the last position:

```
0.00036616624
```

To get a larger number of digits, just increase the precision specifier. For example, using `%.19f` gives:

```
0.0003661662394727206
```

Comment: @shekhar, it _wasn't_ a comment when I started the answer and, in any case, it should have been an _answer_ - that's the way SE is supposed to work, after all :-)

Comment: @shekharsuman your comment encourage me to put a upvote here. :)

Comment: Ok well how would I get the print output to display the number in full? Like 0.0003661662394727206

Comment: @ChrisDLFC: see my update. Outputting floating point values has a default format string but you can change it to something else by _explicitly_ calling `String.format()`.

Answer (score 0):

Both output values are the same but just the format is different

print it the following way

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(out));
```